# How to get font info of a selected text in pdf using pdfbox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, text-extraction, pdf-parsing

I have the coordinates of the selected text in the pdf. And I am using PDFTextStripperByArea to add and extract the region to get the text info.

But I want to get the font info of that selected text. When I use getResources() method of PDFTextStripperByArea class it returns null. Here's the sample code-

```
    PDFTextStripperByArea stripper = new PDFTextStripperByArea();
    stripper.setSortByPosition(true);
    Rectangle2D rect = new Rectangle(96, 150, 101, 11);
    stripper.addRegion("selectedText", rect);
    PDPage firstPage = document.getPage(0);
    stripper.extractRegions(firstPage);
    System.out.println(stripper.getTextForRegion("selectedText"));
    PDResources resources = stripper.getResources();
    // gives a null pointer exception for resources object in the below line
    for (COSName fontName : resources.getFontNames())
    {
        PDFont font = resources.getFont(fontName);

        System.out.println(font.getFontDescriptor().getFontName());
        System.out.println(font.getFontDescriptor().getFontFamily());
        System.out.println(font.getFontDescriptor().getFontWeight());
        System.out.println(font.getName());
        System.out.println(font.getSubType());
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: I have improved the javadoc, because that isn't what getResources of that class is for. Please try the PrintTextLocations example, and try changing it to use PDFTextStripperByArea  instead of PDFTextStripper.

Comment: @swarupn Did a look at `PrintTextLocations` help?